# replacing image of back button in navigation bar results in two back buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c

IOS 11.x I'm trying to replace the back button image of navigation bar to use a custom back arrow. The following code adds the back arrow, but it does not replace the default '<' arrow and now I see two images for one back button.

Here is my code in the view controller that leads up to next view with two back buttons.

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItemWithImage = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItemWithImage;
```

If I comment this code, then the back button becomes '< Back'

[image: navigation bar with one back button but two images]

Please advice on how to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: first hide default back button`self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;` then add your code.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati. Thanks but that didn't work either. I tried all possible ways.

I think I have found a solution. It lies in doing it once under appdelegate . I am testing it now and will update the solution along with another SO post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image"];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't work. I tried 3 different ways: 1. I tried this in addition to the code I had - no change. 2. I removed my code and used just this - I got '< Back' and no custom image. 3. I added your suggestion on the view controller that shows the back button and it made no difference.

Comment: sorry, I now edited my answer adding the missing lines

Comment: Thanks @il3v. I have not tried your solution, it may very well work. But I found a solution that works and is perfect for my situation. I do this only once in appdelegate.m and then all back buttons in my app use this custom image. Please see my post with solution.

Comment: Which is pretty much the same as mine, just an application-wide approach, which can be either better or worse depending on how broad you need it to be. All is well that ends well.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from another SO post here - 
[how to set image on default back button of navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758130/how-to-set-image-on-default-back-button-of-navigation-bar)

The credit for this goes to @Badal Shah.

in app delegate.m replace the image for back button once and now throughout the app the back button will use your custom image instead of default '<'

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [self customBackButtonForNavigationBar];
}

-(void)customBackButtonForNavigationBar {
        //int imageSize = 20;
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backButton"]; //set your backbutton imagename
    UIImage *backButtonImage = [myImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];
        // now use the new backButtomImage
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:backButtonImage];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:backButtonImage];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-400.f, 0)
                                                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

}
```

Now If you want to remove the title for back button then you can do the usual code for that:

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButtonItem;
```

This will make sure your back button has only the image you've set and no title.